# how to use sed to replace string containing parenthesis

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to replace the following but not working

replace `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` with `datetime.utcnow()` recursively

i have tried the following

```
grep -rl "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" . | xargs sed -i 's/datetime.now\(pytz.utc\)/datetime.utcnow\(\)/g'
```

> mac command equivalent

```
LC_ALL=C

grep -e "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" -rl . | xargs sed -i '' 's/datetime.now\(pytz.utc\)/datetime.utcnow\(\)/g'
```

as you can see i tried to escape all the parentheses but does not work

anyone know how to properly use sed to replace `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` with `datetime.utcnow()`?

Comment: Don't escape the brackets, e.g. `echo "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" | sed 's/datetime.now(pytz.utc)/datetime.utcnow()/g'` -> datetime.utcnow() (explained in more detail here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005)

Comment: why not using grep with xargs as i have it? or is that what issue is?

Comment: Because `grep -rl "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" .` returns nothing on my system. I don't have any files that have "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" in them, so I used echo instead to show you how to solve your problem

Comment: If you are having issues with xargs, an alternative is to use find/exec e.g. `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/datetime.now(pytz.utc)/datetime.utcnow()/g' {} \;`

Comment: the grep options i posted works for linux/unix, but not mac, are you using mac? i updated question with command that works on mac that is similar to the grep/xargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to explain in the comments, but obviously I wasn't clear. Here are two potential solutions to your problem:

Using your 'grep/xargs' method:

```
grep -rl "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" . | xargs sed -i 's/datetime.now(pytz.utc)/datetime.utcnow()/g'
```

Using the 'find/exec' method:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/datetime.now(pytz.utc)/datetime.utcnow()/g' {} \;
```

Both options will replace "datetime.now(pytz.utc)" with "datetime.utcnow()" in the files found. Both answers are platform independent provided you have GNU sed, not BSD sed.

Comment: actually you are right..worked without escaping...am not sure what happened here because i believe i tried this first and it never worked..either ways thanks

Comment: No problem - glad you sorted it out :)